# Can users without the required reputation suggest new tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, tags, reputation

On the Stack Exchange boardgames' domain I sadly was not able to submit my response, as the game I was posting about is not so popular ([#](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/48165/where-can-i-find-strategy-discussion-about-dots)). So I just went on and put any random tag on it. I am really thinking something should be done to the reputation system, as it clearly benefits 'veterans' and removes all the 'simple' rights of newcomers (me :D). I think those people should be able **(1)** to create tags, which won't be created at first, only displayed and awaited for approval, **(2)** be able to upvote thankful answers in their topics (as it's obvious that new people will reply a 'thank you', while they shouldn't, as it seems like).

Also, I would strongly recommend **(3)** on any forum the special 'undefined' tag, which will be a ping for experienced people: They can later on help adding correct tags, and show which tags could be used. I mean, if you don't find the correct tag, most of you either create the one they need or use any tag randomly, since one is the minimum, right?

Well, personally, that's how I'd fix a problem. Believe me, no-one reads the terms, every accepts them. Same with new users: I think stack overflow should have something similar to an 'explanation modus', where every button may have a question mark, explaining what it does, how to avoid, etc. For example this meta site here. I only heard 'discussing the site itself here': I am completely sure that this topic gets bumped with off-topic marks, without anyone explaining me, where else? Right? Basically, where do you suggest things to the sites if not here (I made a topic about the site on the meta, it was off-topic, I mean, I just couldn't search/find for what to do in this hopeless situation)?

The last thing I'd suggest is basically not to display the amount of downvotes. Imagine the following scenario: Someone joins stack overflow, and maybe he has searched wrong and couldn't find anything, and maybe even had some spelling mistakes: 31 downvotes, 10 people mark the topic as off-topic, 5 as duplicate.. I clearly know how he would feel because I was in a similar situation: I asked for help and someone just hid my topic. I felt like in dictatorship, where there is no right for opinions. If stack overflow is such a dictatorship, then please redirect me to a nicer forum. Well, I hope it's not, so, no matter who is down there trying to prevent me from asking for help, please don't and remember when you just joined stack overflow. The way reputation currently works is ill for new users: being stuck in the endless circle of 'bad' questions, not becoming better, not having any ability to raise up.

Comment: In short they can't for good reasons.

Comment: *"The way reputation currently works is ill for new users: being stuck in the endless circle of 'bad' questions, not becoming better, not having any ability to raise up."* If that were really the case, then *nobody* would be able to gain any reputation. But many people gain reputation all the time—by posting good questions and answers.

Comment: If you're in an endless circle of bad questions, I would recommend spending more time reading questions that get upvotes, observe how they ask, and read the help center for more information.  Once you've stuck around for a while and have that info, you'll be better equipped to ask better questions.

Comment: We prefer to use the term Q/A site to describe the sites found in the SE network. The term forum, used by other sites like Quora and Reddit, has in general a more broad and open ended, non-restricted content policy. On Q/A sites all there is is a narrow scoped question and their answers.

Comment: @fbueckert: I do, point is, I have not the best grades in languages, so if I read any post I do not know where to pay attention, either.

Comment: That's part of the trick, Anatoly; you need to put in some time and effort to understanding the site you're trying to participate in.  Understanding the language of the site is also important.  Especially pay attention to the Help Center.  There's lots of information in there that can help.

Comment: If you really find it difficult to gain reputation by answering or asking questions why don't you set out on suggesting good edits to posts of others? It requires that you visit and read lots of posts, you'll learn in the process to recognize posts that do well. Don't forget that tags have wiki's as well that need content(but please don't plagiarize that content from around the internet). With a dictionary, creativity, time and some common sense you can earn up to 1000 rep.

Answer (score 4):

The way for new users without the required amount of rep to suggest new tags is once you have enough rep to chat, **drop into the site chat room and ask nicely that the tag be created by someone else with the required rep.**

The other way to do it would be t**o make the suggestion on the meta site and ask there**.

In either case the other site members may still say no, but it usually doesn't hurt to ask.

I will point out that creating tags and doing it properly is hard even for experienced users.

Comment: None of this helps a new user who does not have enough reputation to chat or to post on meta.

Comment: @Gilles 5 rep to ask on meta, 20 to chat, 500 to create tags https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges. They would need all of one upvote on a question to ask a meta post about adding a specific tag